# Extract type from kind

Tags: scala, types, traits, type-alias, higher-kinded-types

I would like to extract the type of a kind, and use it to define the return type of a function.

eg.

Let's define a `Container` trait.

```
trait Container[T] {
  def contained: T
}
```

Let's define an `Extra` trait, so we can extend it from our container.

```
trait Extra[T] {
  def extra: T
}
```

Let's define a trait `ContainerExtractor` as

```
trait ContainerExtractor[T, C <: Container[T]] {
  def extract(container: C): T
}
```

Now users can implement a `ContainerExtractor` by doing

```
new ContainerExtractor[String, Container[String] with Extra[Int]] {
  override def extract(container: Container[String] with Extra[Int]): String = ???
}
```

Not bad, although the user needs to declare the type inside `Container` twice!
`[String, Container[String] ... ]`

To solve this repetition issue, I tried to work around it by redefining `Container` and `ContainerExtractor` as

```
trait Container[T] {
  def contained: T
  final type Contained = T
}

trait ContainerExtractor[C <: Container[_]] {
  def extract(container: C): C#Contained
}
```

This way (I hoped) users that want to implement a `ContainerExtractor` could write:

```
new ContainerExtractor[Container[String] with Extra[Int]] {
  override def extract(container: Container[String] with Extra[Int]): String =???
}
```

Although this fails with:

```
incompatible type in overriding
def extract(container: Test.Container[String] with Test.Extra[Int]): _$2 (defined in trait ContainerExtractor);
found   : (container: Test.Container[String] with Test.Extra[Int])String
required: (container: Test.Container[String] with Test.Extra[Int])_$2
```

Because the compiler cannot infer that the type referred to by the wildcard in `C <: Container[_]` is a `String` in this trait implementation.

Any help with how to avoid having user to define the container type twice when implementing `ContainerExtractor`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type projection by using `Class#T`  gives a generic member type from the Class, instead of a Class instance. In your case, if you just do `C#Contained`, it just refers to the member type of a C. The compiler doesn't know what C is. You should get the member type from the variable instead:

```
trait ContainerExtractor[C <: Container[_]] {
  def extract(container: C): container.Contained
}
```